# Using multiple commands a argument in Cruise Control

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net

I have been trying to create a build for the project using Git, I need to perform multiple git commands as argument where I can get the list of modified files and place them as zip below is the configuration snippet

```
<exec>
        <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe</executable>
        <baseDirectory>C:\myprojectC</baseDirectory>
        <buildArgs>archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only master)</buildArgs>        
</exec>
```

Can anybody help me with the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [config preprocessor](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor) for cruise control then `$` is a special character which has a meaning to the preprocessor, it can be escaped however:

`\$` is the escape sequence you would need to use, thus allows you to execute the exact same command via cruise control that you have performed in the command prompt.

As such you would be able to use the following:

```
<exec>
 <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe</executable>
 <baseDirectory>C:\myprojectC</baseDirectory>
 <buildArgs>archive -o update.zip HEAD \$(git diff --name-only master)</buildArgs>      
</exec>
```